# Replace or Modify Y axis text in the Morris Line Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, morris.js

I am using Morris Graph for showing year by change. But client would not like to see numbers in Y axis instead they would like me to list down Advanced, Intermediate, Beginner and Needs Improvement as Y axis.

I tried to change the text when we initiate the graph but couldnt, hence I tried yet no luck. Even though when i debugg, i can see the element found and being replaced with my text but again the JS replaces with the numberals

```
$(window).load(function() {
debugger;
    $('#individal > div > svg > text:nth-child(11)').empty().append('Advanced');
};
```

http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/

https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

I have made a fiddle for your data

http://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/16s3mea5/

```
yLabelFormat : function (y) { return y; }
```

Comment: That did the job, thanks a ton :-) Have a great noon ahead

Comment: @PrajDb anytime :)